# traversing through a text file and comparing with other and output the concatenated file in unix

Tags: unix

I have a scenario in bash where in i have 2 files emp_details.txt and emp_file.txt. emp_details has the details of employees as below

```
1 emp1 sales
2 emp2 marketng
3 emp3 testing
```

emp_file.txt has

```
1 emp1 30 2500
2 emp2 25 1200
3 emp3 33 4000
```

how do i traverse through these files and create a third file which displays complete details of the emp 1, emp 2 and emp 3
like

```
1 emp1 sales 30 2500
2 emp2 marketing 25 1200
3 emp3 testing  33 4000
```

Comment: use  your cmd line and read documentation for the `join` cmd, i.e. `man join`. You can also search here and on the www for tutorials and examples using `join`. Good luck.

Comment: @diptea, are those line numbers actually in your files?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `awk`:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { emp[$1,$2] = $0; next }
    (($1,$2) in emp) { print emp[$1,$2], $3, $4 }
' emp_details.txt emp_file.txt
1 emp1 sales 30 2500
2 emp2 marketng 25 1200
3 emp3 testing 33 4000
```

If you are on solaris (variant of unix), please do not use the default awk. Use `nawk`, or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`.

If this mocked up data is considerably different that your real data, you might need to tweak the code yourself or update your question and publish data that represents your data more accurately.